Application not visible in Azure Enterprise Applications blade when created using MS Graph in Powershell
I created an app in azure AD using New-MgApplication command of MS Graph in powershell. Then I created service principal of the same app. Both are executed successfully but I cannot see the application in Enterprise Applications Blade on azure portal though it is visible in Azure App registrations blade. Below are the commands that I ran.
New-MgApplication -DisplayName 'oidc auto'

New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


Please check if the service principal is assigned to the application or not through Azure Portal. Also please paste a screenshot of output after you run the above commands.

Initially, I created an app registration in Microsoft Entra ID using below MS Graph PowerShell command:
New-MgApplication -DisplayName 'oidc auto'

Response:

Azure Portal:

Now, I ran this PowerShell command to create service principal for above app registration:
New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

Response:

Azure Portal:

By default, filter will be "Application type==Enterprise Applications" so you cannot see the service principal if you are searching with that filter type:

To find this newly created service principal in Enterprise Applications Blade on Azure portal, make sure to change filter to "All applications" as below:

When I changed the filter to "All applications", I can see the service principal successfully like this:

In your case, make sure to change Application type to "All applications" to find the newly created service principal in Enterprise Applications blade.
